# gem Faker adding a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm seeding some Posts (seeds.rb). But I would like to add locally a method (past_week) in Faker. And I'm getting an error

seeds.rb

```
Post.create(
    :title => Faker::Lorem.words(4),
    :content => Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2)
    :created_at => Faker::Date.past_week
    )
```

faker.rb (in my ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/faker1-3-0

```
require 'time'
require 'date'
require 'faker/date'
```

in my date.rb (in my ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/faker1-3-0/lib

```
module Faker
  class Date < Base
    class << self
      def past_week
        #return a random day in the past 7 days
        today = Date.today
        today = today.downto(today - 7).to_a
        today.shuffle[0]

      end
    end
  end
end
```

my error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `today' for Faker::Date:Class
/home/userlaptop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/faker-1.3.0/lib/faker.rb:138:in `method_missing'
/home/userlaptop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/faker-1.3.0/lib/faker/date.rb:5:in `past_week'
/home/userlaptop/development/public/project/jed/db/seeds.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you've named your class `Date`, `today` is not found as you do not have that method defined.  In order to reference the ruby `Date` class, prefix the class with a scope resolution operator:

```
module Faker
  class Date < Base
    class << self
      def past_week
        #return a random day in the past 7 days
        today = ::Date.today
        today = today.downto(today - 7).to_a
        today.shuffle[0]

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: tanks a lot for the clue. I'll vot your answer will in 3 min.